# NSUserDefaults overriding previously saved values

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I have two completely separate tasks being carried out but somehow they seem to connect.

In ViewController 1, I have:

```
NSString *foo = @"foo";
NSUserDefaults *default1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
[default1 setObject:foo forKey:@"foo"];
[default1 synchronize];
```

and when I do:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"foo"]);
```

The value printed is what I expect it to be.

In ViewController 2, I have:

```
NSString *bar = @"bar";
NSUserDefaults *default2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
[default2 setObject:bar forKey:@"bar"];
[default2 synchronize];
```

And same again when I NSLog it, the value is what I expect it to be.

But somehow when i try to print object `@"foo"` again it gives me the value for the second object, in this case `@"bar"`

Any guidance on why my original value is being overridden by the second value even tough the  variable/key names are different in the 2 classes?

Comment: It's a NSString in both cases

Comment: Replace this line  [foo setObject:foo forKey:@"foo"]; with [default1 setObject:foo forKey:@"foo"];  likewise in second case

Comment: Show the logging code that doesn't print what you expect!

Comment: the code is NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"foo"]); to print the first userdefault >after< i've saved my second userDefault will give me the result @"bar" which is the value of the second object being set

Answer (score 1):

You are doing this for both:

```
[foo setObject:bar forKey:@"bar"];
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
[defaults1 setObject:foo forKey:@"foo"];
```

And

```
[defaults2 setObject:bar forKey:@"bar"];
```

There is however, a greater problem:

```
NSString *foo = @"foo";
NSUserDefaults *default1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[default1 setObject:foo forKey:@"foo"];
[default1 synchronize];

NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"foo"]);

NSString *bar = @"bar";
NSUserDefaults *default2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[default2 setObject:bar forKey:@"bar"];
[default2 synchronize];

NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"bar"]);
```

Will work properly, however you're creating `defaults1` and `defaults2` which are both instances of standard defaults, so:

```
NSUserDefaults * defaults1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSUserDefaults * defaults2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

Are all pointers to the `standardUserDefaults` singleton.  So they are identical instances.  You could simply do:

```
NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString *foo = @"foo";
[standardDefaults setObject:foo forKey:@"foo"];
NSString *bar = @"bar";
[standardDefaults setObject:bar forKey:@"bar"];
[standardDefaults synchronize];

NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"foo"]);
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"bar"]);
```

Comment: sorry, it is like that. I was just trying to copy my example from my project and change it display foo/bar. that was typo on my part, i've edited the question to display the actual code

Comment: foo and bar are in two different classes, so shall I do
[standardDefaults synchronize];
after i've setObject in both classes?

Comment: That is a matter of some debate.  If it's important data that needs to  be protected at all costs, then yes.  Anytime you modify something like that in userDefaults, you should synchronize.  With that being said, userDefaults will cache values and periodically synchronize on its own.  Anytime you call synchronize on userdefaults, all data that is currently cached in the userDefaults will be saved. If a crash occurs before this cache is synchronized, you will lose that data.

Comment: thanks a lot for your knowledgable answer, unfortunately that still doesn't solve my bug, even after I just tried to synchronize my userdefault in the two classes. might have to do some more digging around

Comment: Hmmm, I just ran this code with no problems, so I'm pretty sure your problem is elsewhere, make sure you're properly setting the keys to the appropriate values.  Printing like @user3386109 suggests is probably a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can print out the entire set of user defaults with code like this

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [defaults dictionaryRepresentation];
NSLog( @"%@", dictionary );
```

Note that Apple puts lots of garbage in the user defaults, so you'll have to scroll to the end to see `foo` and `bar`.  I'm guessing that you have a typo in code that you haven't shown us, and either `foo` is being overwritten, or `foo` simply isn't being displayed properly.

The current code in your question (after 1 edit) is all good and should work correctly.